# conditional DirectoryIndex based on IP address, using .htaccess

Tags: apache, htaccess

I've got this in `httpd.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost xx.xxx.xx.xxx>
    Options All +ExecCGI
    ServerAdmin hostmaster@thehost.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain.com
    ServerName  dl.domain.org
    DirectoryIndex dlindex1.html
</VirtualHost>
```

... which is fine (what I need as the `DirectoryIndex` for our 'dl.domain.org' subdomain), *but* now I also need to alter that `DirectoryIndex` based on IP address, using `.htaccess`.
Is this possible?

StackOverflow posts are telling me that I cannot set `DirectoryIndex` conditionally.. but instead *have* to use a `RewriteRule`.
If that is true, OK, but what `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule`?
I am pretty noob in Apache, but anyway have tried many things, including (where the actual IPs are those of our 2 devs):

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^111\.222\.333\.444$    [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^555\.666\.777\.888$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^dl.domain.org
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1/dlindex2.html
```

..or even just (as an absolute test):

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^555\.666\.777\.888$
RewriteRule (.*)/dlindex1.html$ $1/dlindex2.html
```

But it seems that whatever I try it just serves up the `DirectoryIndex dlindex1.html` as per `httpd.conf`, as opposed to the `dlindex2.html` I want served up as the default page in that subdomain when a devs IP is calling.

Can any one point me to what I can do to get what I am after? i.e. this: ...to actually, or even just effectively, alter `DirectoryIndex` based on IP address, using `.htaccess`, on the fly?

Comment: There are a few questions like this on StackOverflow. I would also search on ServerFault http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599717/conditional-directoryindex-in-htaccess

Comment: You mentioned to show a different index when a developers IP is accessing the site? Are you trying to create a development environment?

Comment: I did see that post.. and the accepted answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1599786/530006) gives an internal server error, so I do not see why it is accepted.

Yes I am trying to have Apache serve up a development copy of the default page when my or another dev's IP (...the default page which is only the default page when coming in via a certain sub.domain.

Comment: Why not htpassword the sub domain entirely, give your devs access and let them work on those files directly. You can rsync a complete copy of your server root.

Comment: I am pretty noob here as I said.. but also am not sure that would work well here.. since the subdomain needs to be serving up the default index page, live, to end users (non devs)... and also the devs need to be able to go back and forth (with e.g. a quick tweak to an IP in .htaccess RewriteCond) to compare how code behaves with the live copy of the defaultIndex -vs.- the dev copy of the defaultIndex.
The subdomain is live, not for dev.   I guess I misunderstood what you meant when you asked if I was setting up a dev environ.  "Yes, but not with a subdomain... but with DirectoryIndex"

Comment: Well have a unique sub domain for dev's only. You'll have a live subdomain (production) then another sub domain (development), what CMS if any are you running?

Comment: not using any CMS; this is an old very large custom code base.  I'll have to play with what you just suggested.. and report back, before taking more of your time.

Comment: Subversion is ideal if your developers are familiar with it. Otherwise two subdomains is probably your best bet than messing with .htaccess.

Comment: i am good with git..  but the other devs not so.. and we have bigger issues right now than time will allow to train them.  Anyway  for now I have gone ahead with your suggestion of 2 subdomains.. and will work with that... though I would still eventually like to know if there is a way to (as if) make `DirectoryIndex` conditionally-IP-based, somehow.  Thanks for your help; I'd be glad to accept your answer of using 2 subdomains as a workaround if you want to post it as such... or if not, then I'll answer myself so as not to leave the Q officially unanswered (w/out *accepted* answer).

Comment: Answer posted, i'd also be cautious because your developers may lose their IP if their modems are off long enough or if their ISP makes some kind of update and reboots them. Just guessing they're mostly on DHCP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two subdomains one for the developers which you can make private and secure the other is your live production subdomain